# Show that MN and MP are angle bisectors

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> A $\triangle ABC$ is drawn ($\angle C = 90^\circ$), in which $CL$ $(L
>  \in AB)$ is bisector. The circle $k$ with diameter $CL$ intersects AB,
>   BC and CA, respectively, in $M$, $N$ and $P$. Show that $MN$ and $MP$
>   are angle bisectors of $\angle BMC$ and $\angle AMC$.

[image]

$PMNC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, thus $\angle PMN + \angle PCN = 180^\circ$ and $\angle PMN = 90^\circ$. Also $\angle CML = 90^\circ$. I don't know what to do after this. I would be very grateful if you could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\angle CMB = \angle CMA = 90^\circ$, since $\angle CML$ subtends the diameter $CL$.

By the inscribed angle theorem, $\angle LPC=90^\circ = \angle LNC$

Triangles $LPC$ and $LNC$ are equal (by common side and equal angles), so $CP = CN$ and $CPN$ is an isosceles right triangle.

By the inscribed angle theorem, $\angle CMP=\angle CNP=45^\circ$, so $MP$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CMA$.

Analogically, $MN$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CMB$.

Comment: Thank you! $+1$